# Finding the difference in minutes or seconds for two timestamps in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have two columns in a excel containing value like **: Mon Dec 01 09:27:04 2014.**

Lets say column A and column B and each column has rows containing values in the above format. How can we find the difference between two dates?

`Mon Dec 01 09:27:04 2014 - Sun Nov 30 11:08:36 2014 = 25 hrs 51 minutes`

Comment: Are these numeric values? Test by using `=COUNT(A2,B2)` where the timestamps are in A2 and B2 - if the result is 2 then you can just subtract, i.e. use `=B2-A2` and format result cell as `[h]:mm`

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-HP003056108.aspx) for how to do that..

A more direct answer: you can format the cell

```
=TEXT(B2-A2,"h:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the data is text strings for which I suggest:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,9,2)&"/"&MID(A1,5,3)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4))-VALUE(MID(B1,9,2)&"/"&MID(B1,5,3)&"/"&RIGHT(B1,4))+(MID(A1,12,8)-MID(B1,12,8))
```

However this relies on Excel's ability to interpret the likes of `Dec` as the month of December which may not be the case for all language versions. If so, I suggest a lookup table and extracting the dates with DATE along these lines:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),VLOOKUP(MID(A1,5,3),Table,2,0),MID(A1,9,2))
```

However by such calculation the difference of the timestamps given in the question is:

> 22 hrs 18 minutes 28 seconds

when formatted:

```
[hh] "hrs" mm "minutes" ss "seconds"
```